# Free physical memory in matlab

Tags: matlab, memory

First of all I'd like to say that I've been searching conscientiously about this topic but I haven't found anything about it that can serve to me.

My problem is the following: I'm running an script (not too long) in matlab R2016b . But after several times, the physical memory of my computer starts to run out so the only way to keep it running the code is restarting the program (I can't do this all time I have to run the script).

I use different commands like 'clear', 'close', 'pack', etc; but none works and the program doesn't free the memory after each code. I'm using Windows in a computer with 8Gb memory, so I have a few tries before I have to restart so I can continue to use the computer. The image shows the increases of memory required after the code is run each time.

I'd thank if anyone could help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xYe2.png)

Comment: Excuse me sir, but if you read the question again I'm not talking about free  the physical memory intended to a variable like in the case of the question related to this one. That's the reason why specified that the commands 'clear (variable)' don't work in this case. In my case, the physical memory runs out despite using this kind of commands used to free the memory devoted to variables. I'd thank if this question is taken into account again

Comment: Hi David, I don't have enough reputation to vote to reopen your question, but my advice is to use the "edit" link to add the paragraph that you put in the comments to the **top** of your question. Start with a header "Differences from proposed duplicate", and then write about why `clear` doesn't work. You could even change your title to something like "How to forcibly free physical memory when clear doesn't work". This hopefully will get your question more attention.